# SSRS2019 in IE11, icons are displayed as alphabets in Reportviewer

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2019

On Windows Server 2019,installed SSRS 2019 and configured in report server. when I previewing the reports, all icons will be rendered in capital letters .In server side, any settings need to changed to make it work? Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: "*when I previewing the reports, all icons will be rendered in capital letters*"...so the issue happens on the client side, on your local computer, you're saying?...or it also happens to deployed reports on the server?

Comment: Deployed reports on server  and preview the reports in server side , got alphabets instead of icons.

Comment: How are you previewing reports on the server?...do you have Visual Studio actually installed on the server and are connecting to the machine to run your SSRS project in Visual Studio?

Comment: RDL file uploaded in server and configured in report server configuration manager ,using report viewer  to preview the report. No visual studio installed

Comment: Please see Otter's answer as I'm sure that's what you're experiencing. Internet Explorer 11 is less than a year away for out of lifecycle support from Microsoft, so I'd focus on using a different browser anyway, such as Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue in IE (no surprises there), see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/219776/srss-2019-shows-alpha-characters-instead-of-icons.html) that explains that you could also add the web portal URL to the trusted sites list and Compatibility View Setting in IE options menu.